# What are the OIDC standards that the applications using Auth0 must follow?

Tags: oauth-2.0, auth0, openid-connect

I just want to know brief explanation of OIDC standards that all the applications must follow. I have found a book https://openid.net/specs/openid-connect-core-1_0.html#RFC2119 about OIDC standards but I just want a brief explanation if anybody can provide
Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately the answer is "it depends".  It depends on what you are protecting, how you decide to implement this protection, and if you choose to use the OIDC compliant aspects or not.

A good entry point into this discussion in regards to Auth0 is with their [OIDC Adoption Guide](https://auth0.com/docs/api-auth/tutorials/adoption).  That will link you to many other resources based on what you're looking for.